# Finding all keys that match a value in a nested dictionary and creating a new dictionary with the values as keys

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I've got the following dictionary (much larger obviously):

```
{
'file1': {'parameter1': value,
          'parameter2': value}

'file2': {'parameter1': value,
          'parameter2': value}                          
}
```

I need to turn it into:

```
{
'parameter1': {value1 : [list of all matching files], 
               value2 : [list of all matching files]}

'paramemer2': {value1 : [list of all matching files],
               value2 : [list of all matching files]}
}
```

The number of files and values is arbitrary, the number of parameters is fixed and relatively low.

I'm kinda able to do it, but it requires a lot of intermediate steps, generating sets of all parameters' values etc. Is there a quick pythonic way to invert it? Maybe I should use a different data structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = {
    'file1': {'parameter1': 'value1',
              'parameter2': 'value2'},
    'file2': {'parameter1': 'value1',
              'parameter2': 'value3'}                          
}

dd = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for file, pv_dict in data.items():
    for para, value in pv_dict.items():
        dd[para][value].append(file)

print(dd)
# defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7fb4d89c3c80>, 
#     {
#         'parameter1': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'value1': ['file1', 'file2']}), 
#         'parameter2': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'value2': ['file1'],
#                                                    'value3': ['file2']}), 
#     }
# )
```